# adding a git hub repository script in Tamper Monkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, qr-code, tampermonkey

I have been trying to read QR code though a JavaScript in tamper monkey but I can't seem to get it to work. The error in the console would be (qrcode is not defined) I don't know how to reference the [github repository](https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner) within Tamper Monkey. What I got so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

setInterval(initqrlock(),10000)//click button to show qr code image

setTimeout(func, 3000);// wait 3 seconds

function func() {
    var url = $("#imgcode").attr('src');//find image url
    var url2 = url.match(/(?<=_)[\w+.-]+.+(?=\.)/)//find some use full numbers
    alert(url);//show url
    qrcode.decode(url)// decode image url    problem here
}
```

basic I am trying to read a qr code and open the link within it.

Comment: I cut out the useless information at the top so no one gets confused.

Comment: I do not see where do you `require` the library for qrcode parsing. Anyway, github can't serve JS files, you need to place it somewhere.

Comment: by require I meant by adding the js file to it so I can use qrcode

Comment: I dont mind using another one as long as I know how to use it